# Bash: Splitting a line at whitespace

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to chop out a piece of a line to format a report, scraped from the results of a testssl scan.  I'm looking to chop the line and just take the first half (it looks like it splits on a tab).

Example:

```
Secure Client-Initiated Renegotiation     not vulnerable (OK)
```

I need a way in my bash script (grep, sed, awk, whatever) to pull out just the language of the first part.   The TRICK, I suppose, is that testssl has a lot of tests so I need something that will work no matter what the first part of the line is called (I can't hook onto any of the actual words as those will change).

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is the separation between the two groups of words always 5 white spaces?

Comment: I've tried a lot of grepping.  I've managed to at least strip it down to just finding the lines I need based on the box vulnerabilities but chopping down to just the piece I need has eluded me.

Here's what I'm using to actually get the piece I need:
grep -v "not" FILENAME | egrep -o ".{0,42}VULNERABLE"}

That seems to at least grab from only lines that have a vulnerability (ignoring the not) to the beginning of the line. Now I'm just trying to eliminate the VULNERABLE and the trailing whitespace.

Comment: Here's how the file looks as far as formatting:

 Testing protocols (via openssl, SSLv2 via sockets)

 SSLv2               not offered (OK)
 SSLv3               not offered (OK)
 TLS 1               offered

 Testing vulnerabilities

 Heartbleed (CVE-2014-0160)                not vulnerable (OK), timed out
 CCS (CVE-2014-0224)                       not vulnerable (OK)
 Secure Renegotiation (CVE-2009-3555)      not vulnerable (OK)
 Secure Client-Initiated Renegotiation     VULNERABLE (NOT ok), potential DoS threat

Comment: ...drat the comment doesn't seem to handle formatting cleanly on a paste and I don't see an option to attach a file to the question.

Comment: There's an example of what the output looks like on the project page:  https://testssl.sh/

Answer (score 0):

As you have guessed, you could use a tool like `sed` or `awk` for this purpose. But it is expected that you should provide some effort in the form of code to solve your problem(May be next time?). Anyways I'm taking a bite :

Using `awk` :

```
echo -e "Secure Client-Initiated Renegotiation\tnot vulnerable (OK)" |
awk -FS"\t" '{print $1}'
```

or using `sed` :

```
echo -e "Secure Client-Initiated Renegotiation\tnot vulnerable (OK)" |
sed -E 's/^([^\t]+)\t.*$/\1/'
```

---

<sup>**Note :** In your case, replace `echo` with your command.</sup>

Comment: Much appreciated!  Drat...sigh, it looks like they may have used spacing and not actual tabs to separate the  text in the string.  Both methods just return the entire string as before.  I'll fiddle with the syntax and see if I can whip it into shape.

Honestly, I expected this would somehow devolved into being pulled into some kind of regex purgatory. 

I'm still wrapping my head around scripting through these problems.  I sincerely appreciate the response.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using awk.  Currently I'm running with:

awk -F'   *' '{print $1}'

Which is splitting on more than a few spaces and giving me the first segment (the actual vulnerability found).